# Nginx - Server dead when received many requests

Tags: nginx, mysql, php, php-fpm, google-compute-engine

we have a large Woocommerce website hosted on Google VM servers (E2 4vCPU + 32 GB RAM + 100 GB SSD Storage), recently we created a mobile application using flutter and WordPress -Woocommerce- API, but we faced a two issues

- fetching data is very slow, to load a product maybe it will take more than 5-10 seconds on a HighSpeed Internet connection
- if the user using the app, the website will take more time to load or down, it seems the server dealing with a single request only at the same time

Environment Details

```
server NGINX + MySQL + PHP-FPM
PHP 7.4
OS: Centos 8
All tables Engin - InnoDB
```

we did the following

- increased PHP.ini memory limit to 128MB
- increased PHP.ini timeout limit to 3000 sec
  Linked website with cloudflare. - Installed Cache Plugin W3 Total Cache
- Increase NGINX MAX Clients to 250

I am looking for a suggestion on how I can allow the to server/MySQL to handle a lot of requests.

PHP-FPM Config

```
pm.max_children = 250
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 150
;pm.max_requests = 500
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
;request_terminate_timeout = 0
;rlimit_core = 0
;rlimit_files = 1024
pm.process_idle_timeout = 3000s;
;pm.max_requests = 500
pm = ondemand
; process.priority = -19
```

PHP ini

```
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300
implicit_flush = Off
;unserialize_max_depth = 4096
;realpath_cache_size = 4096k
;realpath_cache_ttl = 120
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
max_input_time = 6000
max_execution_time = 3000
;max_input_nesting_level = 64
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 800M
;mysqlnd.mempool_default_size = 16000
;mysqlnd.net_read_timeout = 31536000
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

PHP-FPM www-status, when the app opening

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      ondemand
start time:           03/Feb/2023:11:59:36 +0000
start since:          25801
accepted conn:        14613
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       0
active processes:     250
total processes:      250
max active processes: 250
max children reached: 250
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  14270
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:08:39 +0000
start since:          58
requests:             17
request duration:     563199
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14272
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             12
request duration:     267198
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14273
state:                Finishing
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             7
request duration:     5577206
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14274
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             7
request duration:     2475191
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14275
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             8
request duration:     2731158
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?status=publish&category=189&orderby=popularity&per_page=5&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14276
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:04 +0000
start since:          33
requests:             8
request duration:     934026
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14277
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     3243188
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14278
state:                Finishing
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     5822217
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14279
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             7
request duration:     220
request method:       GET
request URI:          /www-status?full
content length:       0
```

Database config

```
activate_all_roles_on_login OFF     
auto_generate_certs ON  
auto_increment_increment    1   
auto_increment_offset   1   
autocommit  ON  
automatic_sp_privileges ON  
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF 
back_log    151 
big_tables  OFF 
binlog_cache_size   32768   
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF 
binlog_encryption   OFF 
binlog_error_action ABORT_SERVER    
binlog_expire_logs_seconds  2592000 
binlog_format   ROW 
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  0   
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0   
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery ON  
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0   
binlog_order_commits    ON  
binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup  OFF 
binlog_row_event_max_size   8192    
binlog_row_image    FULL    
binlog_row_metadata MINIMAL 
binlog_row_value_options        
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF 
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768   
binlog_transaction_compression  OFF 
binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd   3   
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size  25000   
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  COMMIT_ORDER    
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb 
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608 
check_proxy_users   OFF 
completion_type NO_CHAIN    
concurrent_insert   AUTO    
connect_timeout 10  
core_file   OFF 
create_admin_listener_thread    OFF 
cte_max_recursion_depth 1000    
default_storage_engine  InnoDB  
default_table_encryption    OFF 
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB  
default_week_format 0   
delay_key_write ON  
delayed_insert_limit    100 
delayed_insert_timeout  300 
delayed_queue_size  1000    
disabled_storage_engines        
div_precision_increment 4   
end_markers_in_json OFF 
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF 
eq_range_index_dive_limit   200 
error_count 0   
event_scheduler ON  
expire_logs_days    0   
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON  
external_user       
flush   OFF 
flush_time  0   
foreign_key_checks  ON  
ft_max_word_len 84  
ft_min_word_len 4   
ft_query_expansion_limit    20  
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)  
general_log OFF 
group_concat_max_len    1024    
group_replication_consistency   EVENTUAL    
gtid_executed       
gtid_executed_compression_period    0   
gtid_mode   OFF 
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC       
have_compress   YES 
have_dynamic_loading    YES 
have_geometry   YES 
have_openssl    YES 
have_profiling  YES 
have_query_cache    NO  
have_rtree_keys YES 
have_ssl    YES 
have_statement_timeout  YES 
have_symlink    DISABLED    
histogram_generation_max_mem_size   20000000    
host_cache_size 279 
identity    0   
immediate_server_version    999999  
information_schema_stats_expiry 86400       
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON  
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10  
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON  
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8   
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000  
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5   
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF 
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF 
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF 
innodb_api_trx_level    0   
innodb_autoextend_increment 64  
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    2   
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728   
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON  
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25  
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool  
innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file ON  
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    1   
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON  
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728   
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25  
innodb_change_buffering all 
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32   
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF 
innodb_commit_concurrency   0   
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5   
innodb_compression_level    6   
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50  
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000    
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend  
innodb_data_home_dir        
innodb_deadlock_detect  ON  
innodb_dedicated_server OFF 
innodb_default_row_format   dynamic 
innodb_directories      
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF 
innodb_doublewrite  ON  
innodb_doublewrite_batch_size   0   
innodb_doublewrite_dir      
innodb_doublewrite_files    2   
innodb_doublewrite_pages    4   
innodb_extend_and_initialize    ON  
innodb_fast_shutdown    1   
innodb_file_per_table   ON  
innodb_fill_factor  100 
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1   
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1   
innodb_flush_method fsync   
innodb_flush_neighbors  0   
innodb_flush_sync   ON  
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30  
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF 
innodb_force_recovery   0   
innodb_fsync_threshold  0   
innodb_ft_aux_table     
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000 
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF 
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON  
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84  
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3   
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000    
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000  
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table     
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2   
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000   
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table       
innodb_idle_flush_pct   100 
innodb_io_capacity  200 
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000    
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50  
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216    
innodb_log_checksums    ON  
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON  
innodb_log_file_size    50331648    
innodb_log_files_in_group   2   
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./  
innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm 80  
innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm 50  
innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm  400 
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192    
innodb_log_writer_threads   ON  
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024    
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  90.000000   
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  10.000000   
innodb_max_purge_lag    0   
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0   
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824  
innodb_monitor_disable      
innodb_monitor_enable       
innodb_monitor_reset        
innodb_monitor_reset_all        
innodb_numa_interleave  OFF 
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37  
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000    
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728   
innodb_open_files   4000    
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF 
innodb_page_cleaners    1   
innodb_page_size    16384   
innodb_parallel_read_threads    4   
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF 
innodb_print_ddl_logs   OFF 
innodb_purge_batch_size 300 
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128 
innodb_purge_threads    4   
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF 
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56  
innodb_read_io_threads  4   
innodb_read_only    OFF 
innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs        
innodb_redo_log_encrypt OFF 
innodb_replication_delay    0   
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF 
innodb_rollback_segments    128 
innodb_segment_reserve_factor   12.500000   
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576 
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6   
innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier   50  
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON  
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF 
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal 
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF 
innodb_stats_persistent ON  
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20  
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8   
innodb_status_output    OFF 
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF 
innodb_strict_mode  ON  
innodb_sync_array_size  1   
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30  
innodb_table_locks  ON  
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend   
innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir ./#innodb_temp/ 
innodb_thread_concurrency   0   
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000   
innodb_tmpdir       
innodb_undo_directory   ./  
innodb_undo_log_encrypt OFF 
innodb_undo_log_truncate    ON  
innodb_undo_tablespaces 2   
innodb_use_fdatasync    OFF 
innodb_use_native_aio   ON  
innodb_validate_tablespace_paths    ON  
innodb_version  8.0.26  
innodb_write_io_threads 4   
insert_id   0   
interactive_timeout 28800   
internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine TempTable   
join_buffer_size    262144  
keep_files_on_create    OFF 
key_buffer_size 8388608 
key_cache_age_threshold 300 
key_cache_block_size    1024    
key_cache_division_limit    100 
keyring_operations  ON  
large_files_support ON  
large_page_size 0   
large_pages OFF 
last_insert_id  0   
lc_messages ar_AE   
lc_time_names   en_US   
license GPL 
local_infile    OFF 
lock_wait_timeout   31536000    
locked_in_memory    OFF 
log_bin ON  
log_bin_basename    /var/lib/mysql/binlog   
log_bin_index   /var/lib/mysql/binlog.index 
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF 
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF 
log_error   /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log   
log_error_services  log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal  
log_error_suppression_list      
log_error_verbosity 2   
log_output  FILE    
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF 
log_raw OFF 
log_replica_updates ON  
log_slave_updates   ON  
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF 
log_slow_extra  OFF 
log_slow_replica_statements OFF 
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF 
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog    ON  
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0   
log_timestamps  UTC 
long_query_time 10.000000   
low_priority_updates    OFF 
lower_case_file_system  OFF 
lower_case_table_names  0   
mandatory_roles     
master_info_repository  TABLE   
master_verify_checksum  OFF 
max_allowed_packet  67108864    
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520    
max_binlog_size 1073741824  
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520    
max_connect_errors  100 
max_connections 151 
max_delayed_threads 20  
max_digest_length   1024    
max_error_count 1024    
max_execution_time  0   
max_heap_table_size 16777216    
max_insert_delayed_threads  20  
max_join_size   18446744073709551615    
max_length_for_sort_data    4096    
max_points_in_geometry  65536   
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382   
max_relay_log_size  0   
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615    
max_sort_length 1024    
max_sp_recursion_depth  0   
max_user_connections    0   
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615    
min_examined_row_limit  0   
myisam_data_pointer_size    6   
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232 
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615    
myisam_recover_options  OFF 
myisam_repair_threads   1   
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608 
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal   
myisam_use_mmap OFF 
mysqlx_bind_address *   
mysqlx_compression_algorithms   DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM  
mysqlx_connect_timeout  30  
mysqlx_deflate_default_compression_level    3   
mysqlx_deflate_max_client_compression_level 5   
mysqlx_document_id_unique_prefix    0   
mysqlx_enable_hello_notice  ON  
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   60  
mysqlx_interactive_timeout  28800   
mysqlx_lz4_default_compression_level    2   
mysqlx_lz4_max_client_compression_level 8   
mysqlx_max_allowed_packet   67108864    
mysqlx_max_connections  100 
mysqlx_min_worker_threads   2   
mysqlx_port_open_timeout    0   
mysqlx_read_timeout 30      
mysqlx_wait_timeout 28800   
mysqlx_write_timeout    60  
mysqlx_zstd_default_compression_level   3   
mysqlx_zstd_max_client_compression_level    11  
net_buffer_length   16384   
net_read_timeout    30  
net_retry_count 10  
net_write_timeout   60  
new OFF 
ngram_token_size    2   
offline_mode    OFF 
old OFF 
old_alter_table OFF 
open_files_limit    10000   
optimizer_prune_level   1   
optimizer_search_depth  62  
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_so...   
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off    
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=...   
optimizer_trace_limit   1   
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    1048576 
optimizer_trace_offset  -1  
original_commit_timestamp   36028797018963968   
original_server_version 999999  
parser_max_mem_size 18446744073709551615    
partial_revokes OFF 
performance_schema  ON  
performance_schema_accounts_size    -1  
performance_schema_digests_size 10000   
performance_schema_error_size   4946    
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000   
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10  
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_...   10000   
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10  
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_lon...   10000   
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_siz...   10  
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000   
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10  
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1  
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 100 
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1  
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024    
performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age    60  
performance_schema_max_file_classes 80  
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768   
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1  
performance_schema_max_index_stat   -1  
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   450 
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   -1  
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    300 
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1  
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instanc...   -1  
performance_schema_max_program_instances    -1  
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   60  
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1  
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10  
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1  
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  1024    
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    175 
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    218 
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  10  
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1  
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1  
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  -1  
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   100 
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1  
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512 
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    -1  
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   -1  
performance_schema_show_processlist OFF 
performance_schema_users_size   -1  
persist_only_admin_x509_subject     
persisted_globals_load  ON      
preload_buffer_size 32768   
print_identified_with_as_hex    OFF 
profiling   OFF 
profiling_history_size  15  
protocol_compression_algorithms zlib,zstd,uncompressed  
protocol_version    10  
proxy_user      
pseudo_replica_mode OFF 
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF 
pseudo_thread_id    975 
query_alloc_block_size  8192    
query_prealloc_size 8192    
rand_seed1  0   
rand_seed2  0   
range_alloc_block_size  4096    
range_optimizer_max_mem_size    8388608 
rbr_exec_mode   STRICT  
read_buffer_size    131072  
read_only   OFF 
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144  
regexp_stack_limit  8000000 
regexp_time_limit   32  
relay_log_info_repository   TABLE   
relay_log_purge ON  
relay_log_recovery  OFF 
relay_log_space_limit   0   
replica_allow_batching  OFF 
replica_checkpoint_group    512 
replica_checkpoint_period   300 
replica_compressed_protocol OFF 
replica_exec_mode   STRICT  
replica_max_allowed_packet  1073741824  
replica_net_timeout 60  
replica_parallel_type   DATABASE    
replica_parallel_workers    0   
replica_pending_jobs_size_max   134217728   
replica_preserve_commit_order   OFF 
replica_skip_errors OFF 
replica_sql_verify_checksum ON  
replica_transaction_retries 10  
replica_type_conversions        
replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config   OFF 
replication_sender_observe_commit_only  OFF 
require_row_format  OFF 
require_secure_transport    OFF 
resultset_metadata  FULL    
rpl_read_size   8192    
rpl_stop_replica_timeout    31536000    
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000    
schema_definition_cache 256 
secondary_engine_cost_threshold 100000.000000   
select_into_buffer_size 131072  
select_into_disk_sync   OFF 
select_into_disk_sync_delay 0   
server_id   1   
server_id_bits  32  
server_uuid 5d22fdf7-9122-11ed-864a-42010ad00002    
session_track_gtids OFF 
session_track_schema    ON  
session_track_state_change  OFF 
session_track_system_variables  time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,characte...   
session_track_transaction_info  OFF 
show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine OFF 
show_create_table_verbosity OFF 
show_old_temporals  OFF 
skip_external_locking   ON  
skip_name_resolve   OFF 
skip_networking OFF 
skip_replica_start  OFF 
skip_show_database  OFF 
skip_slave_start    OFF 
slave_allow_batching    OFF 
slave_checkpoint_group  512 
slave_checkpoint_period 300 
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF 
slave_exec_mode STRICT  
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824  
slave_net_timeout   60  
slave_parallel_type DATABASE    
slave_parallel_workers  0   
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 134217728   
slave_preserve_commit_order OFF 
slave_rows_search_algorithms    INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN    
slave_skip_errors   OFF 
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON  
slave_transaction_retries   10  
slave_type_conversions      
slow_launch_time    2   
slow_query_log  OFF 
sort_buffer_size    262144  
source_verify_checksum  OFF 
sql_auto_is_null    OFF 
sql_big_selects ON  
sql_buffer_result   OFF 
sql_log_bin ON  
sql_log_off OFF 
sql_mode    ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_...   
sql_notes   ON  
sql_quote_show_create   ON  
sql_replica_skip_counter    0   
sql_require_primary_key OFF 
sql_safe_updates    OFF 
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615    
sql_slave_skip_counter  0   
sql_warnings    OFF 
ssl_ca  ca.pem  
ssl_capath      
ssl_cert    server-cert.pem 
ssl_cipher      
ssl_crl     
ssl_crlpath     
ssl_fips_mode   OFF 
ssl_key server-key.pem  
stored_program_cache    256 
stored_program_definition_cache 256 
super_read_only OFF 
sync_binlog 1   
sync_master_info    10000   
sync_relay_log  10000   

sync_relay_log_info 10000   
sync_source_info    10000   
system_time_zone    UTC 
table_definition_cache  2000    
table_encryption_privilege_check    OFF 
table_open_cache    4000    
table_open_cache_instances  16  
tablespace_definition_cache 256 
temptable_max_mmap  1073741824  
temptable_max_ram   1073741824  
temptable_use_mmap  ON  
terminology_use_previous    NONE    
thread_cache_size   9   
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection   
thread_stack    286720  
time_zone   SYSTEM  
timestamp   1675493173.846581   
tls_ciphersuites        
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3   
tmp_table_size  16777216    
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192    
transaction_allow_batching  OFF 
transaction_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ 
transaction_prealloc_size   4096    
transaction_read_only   OFF 
transaction_write_set_extraction    XXHASH64    
unique_checks   ON  
updatable_views_with_limit  YES 
use_secondary_engine    ON      
version 8.0.26  
version_comment Source distribution 
version_compile_machine x86_64  
version_compile_os  Linux   
version_compile_zlib    1.2.11  
wait_timeout    28800   
warning_count   0   
windowing_use_high_precision    ON
```

Comment: 1) All PHP 7.x releases are now end of life, so you shouldn't be with 7.4. 2) Similarly, CentOS 8 reached end of life a year ago. 3) For slow responses, did you observe any clear pattern yet? Did they happen under high load or any time? You will need a lot of knowledge on PHP and database, so as to dive deeper to learn where the slow comes from. Usually you need the original developers or an experienced consultant to assist. I don't think it is an easy task that anyone can help over a site like this, where not enough details are yet revealed.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to avoid what looks like dead.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @mohammad If you could post some of the data requested Feb 6, 2023, we would provide suggestions to assist with avoiding a dead server when busy. View profile for contact info. –